# Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Tags: c#, .net

I'm implementing an achievement system to my game and i can not find the way to solve this error:

```
error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' expression to type  `System.Collections.Generic.List<Achievement>'
```

This is my code

```
public AchievementsManager( )
{
    _achievementKeeper = new Dictionary<AchievementType, int>();
    // ideally, load here previous, saved values.
    // tap = 0
    // die = 1
    // start = 12
    // score = 1231

    _achievements = new Dictionary<AchievementType, List<Achievement>>();

    List<string> listStart = new List<string>();
    listStart.Add(new Achievement() { countToUnlock = 3, isUnlocked = false, Message = "First Time Playing!" });
    listStart.Add(new Achievement() { countToUnlock = 8, isUnlocked = false, Message = "Fifth Time is the Charm?" });
    listStart.Add(new Achievement() { countToUnlock = 10, isUnlocked = false, Message = "Hello and Welcome Back!" });
    listStart.Add(new Achievement() { countToUnlock = 16, isUnlocked = false, Message = "Tapping Time!!" });
    listStart.Add(new Achievement() { countToUnlock = 50, isUnlocked = false, Message = "Perseverance Lvl 1!" });

    _achievements.Add(AchievementType.Start, listStart );
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to point out the line that raises the error.

Comment: So many duplicates to choose from ... just look at the right side of the page ("Related") and pick one.

Comment: Make `listStart` a `List<Achievement>` instead of `List<string>`

Comment: `List<string> listStart = new List<string>(); listStart.Add(new Achievement())` what exactly do you expect to happen here?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer The OPs problem has nothing to do with con-/contra-variance, he´s just adding instances of `AchieveMent` to a list of string, which is not possible at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, I copied the wrong duplicate apparently.

Comment: that's strange, how you managed to reach at the error "cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" .. it must be "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Achievement' to 'string'"  .. you must have receive the error at first .Add section for your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listStart` is of type `List<string>` but you are adding to it `Achievement` objects. Change it to

```
List<Achievement> listStart = new List<Achievement>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `List<string> listStart`, but you are dealing with it as with a `List<Achievement>` .
Replace  this line

```
List<string> listStart = new List<string>();
```

with this one:

```
List<Achievement> listStart = new List<Achievement>();
```